# Bones affecting the mirrored mesh

Tags: bones

I'm following a tutorial on how to make an avatar (I'm hoping to use it in vrchat). The mesh avatar is mirrored, and I named the bones with left/right so it should affect them correctly, but in pose mode when I move one arm, the mesh gets moved on the other side as well when I move the right, but when I move the left, nothing happens with the mesh. I am new to blender so detailed answers are appreciated.
[image: Character normal]
[image: Character bone problem]
[image: Character bone problem 2]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You see that little X button? Above the XYZ widget at the top right of the 3D viewport? You gotta click that button to toggle mirroring, and it stays solitary to edit and pose mode. If its off in both and you turn it on in one it'll stay off for the other.

Comment: @moonboots i attached what i hope is the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem! When I duplicated the first side to the other and renamed it to flip them, it did not get rid of the ".001" from dupli automatically, and that's what was making the other side go wacky. I'm annoyed how easy of a fix it was.